# how can I get my php array data to persist?

Tags: php

When I query the data within the foreach loop it works, but makes a duplicate for each pass in the loop.  I try to var_dump it anywhere else outside the loop and the data isn't there.  Why won't my data persist outside the forEach loop?

```
    <?php


    $old_array = [10-2, 13=>"3452", 4=>"Green", 
5=>"Green", 6=>"Blue", "green"=>"green",
 "two"=>"green" ,"2"=>"green" , "rulebreak" =>"GrEeN", 
"ninja"=>"   Green ", ["blue" => "green", "green"=>"green", 2  => "itsGreen"] ];

$newArray = array();

function filter_Green($array) {



$find = "green";
$replace = "not green";

/* Same result as using str_replace on an array, but does so recursively for multi-dimensional arrays */
/* found here: 

if (!is_array($array)) {
  /* Used ireplace so that searches can be case insensitive */
  return str_ireplace($find, $replace, $array);
}


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

  $newArray[$key] = $value;
  if ($key == "green") {
    $newArray[$key] = "not green";
  }
  if ($value == "green") {
    $newArray[$value] = "not green";
  }


}

return $newArray;

}

filter_Green($old_array);

    var_dump($newArray);
?>
```

Expectation: When I run the function it should replace all instances of "green" with "not green" and save those into a `$newArray`.  I have it returning $newArray but even then it doesn't seem to match up that the values are being saved into the newArray, hence why I'm doing var_dump to check if it's even working (it appears to not be)

Results:  as it is setup, I get an empty array returned to me...It seems to work somewhat if I move var_dump($newArray) to within the foreach loop but that then duplicates the data for each pass.

Comment: Please edit your question. What is the current output and what is the expected output.

Comment: Where do you place the var_dump? if it is inside the function (after the loop) it will work fine, if it's outside the function it won't work because $newArray is defined inside the scope of the function, you should assign the returned value to another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want var_dump `$newArray` out side the function then you should declare `$newArray` as  `global` in your function

```
<?php


$old_array = [10-2, 13=>"3452", 4=>"Green", 5=>"Green", 6=>"Blue", "green"=>"green", "two"=>"green" ,"2"=>"green" , "rulebreak" =>"GrEeN", "ninja"=>"   Green ", ["blue" => "green", "green"=>"green", 2  => "itsGreen"] ];

$newArray = array();

function filter_Green($array) {
global $newArray;


$find = "green";
$replace = "not green";

/* Same result as using str_replace on an array, but does so recursively for multi-dimensional arrays */

if (!is_array($array)) {
  /* Used ireplace so that searches can be case insensitive */
  return str_ireplace($find, $replace, $array);
}


foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

  $newArray[$key] = $value;
  if ($key == "green") {
    $newArray[$key] = "not green";
  }
  if ($value == "green") {
    $newArray[$value] = "not green";
  }


}

return $newArray;

}

filter_Green($old_array);
var_dump($newArray);

?>
```

But instead of declaring `global` in function, use returned value by  `filter_Green($old_array);` as below

```
$result = filter_Green($old_array);
var_dump($result);
```

Comment: good call on storing functions result onto a variable, that will do the trick ;)